# Windows 7 Libraries

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-shell

I hope someone can help me with this, as I'm unable to find the right method to do it.

I am currently developing an application that should, in part, be able to enumerate all the Windows Libraries and display their contents.

For now, I am able to get the included folders for all the standard Windows 7 libraries (Documents, Pictures, Videos and Music, etc).

The problem is that I don't know how to get the info of custom user-defined Libraries, as the `IShellLibrary::SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder()` needs the specific folder `GUID`, which is not really defined in `KnownFolders.h`.

I only need to list all Libraries' names and fetch their respective `GUID`s, if it's possible.

Comment: OMG, a whole day and I didn't even get a single comment

Come on guys, any suggestions are acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can technically create a library definition file and place it anywhere on a system.  Short of searching for *all* such definition files, perhaps you might consider limiting yourself to enumerating all shell items under the well-known shell folder `FOLDERID_Libraries`?  The ID for this folder should be in `KnownFolders.h` in the latest version of the Windows SDK.

For each shell item that you come across under this folder, you should be able to call [`SHLoadLibraryFromItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378434(VS.85).aspx) to "load" the library if you need access to an `IShellLibrary` object for it.

Comment: Thx man already done that and now everything works thx for the reply